# How to move methods out of app delegate?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I am trying to move methods out of app delegate and instead using a separate view controller to conform to the protocol. 
The old app delegate is :

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.qnaire = [[VRQuestionnaire alloc] initWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"set1"
                                                                                        ofType:@"json"]];

    self.navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [self prepareForQuestion:self.qnaire.firstQuestion animated:NO];

    return YES;
}

/* Set up the question view controller with a question and push onto the nav stack
 */
- (void)prepareForQuestion:(VRQuestion *)question animated:(BOOL)animated;
{
    VRQuestionViewController *qvc = (VRQuestionViewController *)[self.navController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"QuestionViewController"];
    qvc.delegate = self;

    qvc.question = question;
    [self.navController pushViewController:qvc animated:animated];
}

/* Delegate that gets called every time a question is answered. This loads the next question and pushes it onto the nav stack.
 It also pushes a pointer to the question and result to a linked-list called firstAnswer->nextAnswer->nextAnswer, etc.

 When the next question returns nil we know we've finished as there are no more questions and log linked-list to console.
 */
- (void)questionViewController:(VRQuestionViewController *)controller didAnswerQuestion:(VRQuestion *)question withResult:(BOOL)result
{
    VRQuestion *nextQuestion = nil;

    if (result == YES) {
        nextQuestion = question.nextYesQuestion;
    } else if (result == NO) {
        nextQuestion = question.nextNoQuestion;
    }
    [self.qnaire pushAnswerResult:result forQuestion:question];

    // Handle no more questions
    if(nextQuestion) {
        [self prepareForQuestion:nextQuestion animated:YES];

    } else {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Complete"
                                                            message:@"You completed the questionnaire"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [self.qnaire logAnswers];
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to move these methods to InitialViewController , but the button does nothing ?

```
@implementation InitialViewController
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.qnaire = [[VRQuestionnaire alloc] initWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"set1"
                                                                                        ofType:@"json"]];
    //self.navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [self prepareForQuestion:self.qnaire.firstQuestion animated:NO];

}
```

Thanks in advance.

InitialViewController button should call VRQuestionViewController (given below)

```
@interface VRQuestionViewController ()

@end

@implementation VRQuestionViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    self.label.text = self.question.text;
    self.title = [self.question.identifier uppercaseString];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)yesPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (self.delegate != nil) {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(questionViewController:didAnswerQuestion:withResult:)]) {
            [self.delegate questionViewController:self didAnswerQuestion:self.question withResult:YES];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)noPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (self.delegate != nil) {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(questionViewController:didAnswerQuestion:withResult:)]) {
            [self.delegate questionViewController:self didAnswerQuestion:self.question withResult:NO];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

---

My current AppDelegate:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VRQuestionnaire.h"
#import "VRQuestionViewController.h"

@interface VRAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) VRQuestionnaire *qnaire;


@end



#import "VRAppDelegate.h"
#import "VRQuestionViewController.h"

@implementation VRAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.qnaire = [[VRQuestionnaire alloc] initWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"set1"
                                                                                        ofType:@"json"]];


    return YES;
}
```

And InitialViewController:

```
#import "VRAppDelegate.h"
#import "VRQuestionViewController.h"

@implementation VRAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.qnaire = [[VRQuestionnaire alloc] initWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"set1"
                                                                                        ofType:@"json"]];


    return YES;
}

#import "InitialViewController.h"

@interface InitialViewController ()

@end

@implementation InitialViewController
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.qnaire = [[VRQuestionnaire alloc] initWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"set1"
                                                                                        ofType:@"json"]];

    self.navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    [self prepareForQuestion:self.qnaire.firstQuestion animated:NO];


}



/* Set up the question view controller with a question and push onto the nav stack
 */
- (void)prepareForQuestion:(VRQuestion *)question animated:(BOOL)animated;
{
    VRQuestionViewController *qvc = (VRQuestionViewController *)[self.navController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"QuestionViewController"];
    qvc.delegate = self;

    qvc.question = question;
    [self.navController pushViewController:qvc animated:animated];
}

/* Delegate that gets called every time a question is answered. This loads the next question and pushes it onto the nav stack.
 It also pushes a pointer to the question and result to a linked-list called firstAnswer->nextAnswer->nextAnswer, etc.

 When the next question returns nil we know we've finished as there are no more questions and log linked-list to console.
 */
- (void)questionViewController:(VRQuestionViewController *)controller didAnswerQuestion:(VRQuestion *)question withResult:(BOOL)result
{
    VRQuestion *nextQuestion = nil;

    if (result == YES) {
        nextQuestion = question.nextYesQuestion;
    } else if (result == NO) {
        nextQuestion = question.nextNoQuestion;
    }
    [self.qnaire pushAnswerResult:result forQuestion:question];

    // Handle no more questions
    if(nextQuestion) {
        [self prepareForQuestion:nextQuestion animated:YES];

    } else {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Complete"
                                                            message:@"You completed the questionnaire"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [self.qnaire logAnswers];
    }
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Have CTRL-drag from nav controller to make InitialViewController root view controller.
CTRL-dragged from button to VRQuestionViewController.

In simulator when press button VRQuestionViewController is shown with no question or response to Y/N

Sorry am making a real pigs ear if this!

Comment: Why a view controller? It looks more like you should have a question or questionnaire controller. Presumably your current issue is that `self.navController` is nil ?

Comment: exactly self.navController is nil .. am stuck!

Comment: Is `InitialViewController` the root view controller in your navigation controller?

Comment: I have a navigation controller marked as initial view controller

Comment: Just deleted this so InitialViewController marked in storyboard as initial view controller - same issue though

Comment: That isn't what I asked, is an instance of the class named `InitialViewController` set as the root view controller of your initial navigation controller ?

Comment: No - how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in question seems to be the example code on Github listed at https://github.com/rwarrender/DynamicQuestions

For the sake of readability quite a bit of the logic happens in the app delegate. The app delegate initialises the `VRQuestionnaire` instance and sets up the questions. It then sets up the first question view controller on the navigation controller. Each `VRQuestionViewController` is configured so the app delegate is the `VRQuestionViewController`s delegate too. Once a question has been answered, it calls back `questionViewController:didAnswerQuestion:withResult:` where the app delegate pushs the result onto the questionnaire's answer list and then moves along the question tree to display the next question.

As Wain has suggested if you wanted to expand this to more than an example you would probably move the app delete code into a controller class. You're having trouble with your initial view controller class because everything is wrapped inside a navigation controller, therefore your navigation controller should be the initial view controller in the storyboard with your `InitialViewController` class as the root view controller of the navigation controller. You do this by right click dragging from the navigation controller in the storyboard to the `InitialViewController`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That helps but am still missing something here - have updated my question

Comment: @Wain I have set InitialViewController as root controller as you and @Electron have advised. I am finding qvc returning nil whereas in the original code it is an instance of VRQuestionViewController. 
`- (void)prepareForQuestion:(VRQuestion *)question animated:(BOOL)animated;
{
    VRQuestionViewController *qvc = (VRQuestionViewController *)[self.navController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"QuestionViewController"];
    qvc.delegate = self;
    qvc.question = question; //qvc nil
    [self.navController pushViewController:qvc animated:animated];
}`